# Chromedriver is always incorrect version (only supports Chrome version 76)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to start a selenium project using Chrome Driver. Before writing my code, I checked my version of Chrome Driver; currently, I am running version Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit). 
I then went to https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads to download ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.36 and ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.16. I tested each .exe individually. I also placed each .exe in the same directory as my python file. I get errors when running basic code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = "chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

The error I get is this for each version of chrome driver that I test (80-76)

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76
```

When I run the code, chrome briefly pops up, so it doesn't seem like it is an issue with the placement of my .exe. One possible reason why this isn't working is that my version of windows is x64 and the only downloads that seem to be available are for windows 32.

In addition to testing those two versions of chrome driver, I tested all versions for chrome 80-76 and I still get the "76" error. Does anyone know why this is happening? I don't want to roll my Chrome install back to version 76 if I don't have to, but I cant come up with another solution.

Comment: you have 76 version chromedriver and you need 79. Just replace it with the right one.

Comment: I've tried doing that with every chromedriver version, including the two 79 versions available right now

Comment: Could be a path issue. run `chromedriver` from cmd.exe to check the version. run `where chromedriver` to find the path

Comment: I ended up just launching a t2.micro instance on aws and running my code from there and it seems to be working so far. When my code is finished, I will deploy on aws so this a good solution in the meantime